# How pass parameter to helpers using angular-meteor without blaze template

Tags: javascript, helper, angular-meteor

This was possible with Blaze: how do I have to do it in angular-meteor without blaze template? Kindly help me

```
  Template.dummy.helpers({
  getImage: function(imageId) {
  return Images.findOne(imageId);
       }
       });

    {{ getImage '1234' }}
```

How this will happened in helpers of angular-meteor kindly correct my syntax if I am making any mistake as I am new to angular-meteor

This is my code:

```
<tr  class="ng-scope" align="center" ng-repeat="wordsList in addBundle.words(bundles)">
   this.helpers({
                words: (bundles) => {
                return words.find({});
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

So in angular-meteor there is no need to pass parameters to the helpers because you can and should use regular Angular's scope variables.

In your case, you also want to make them reactive (trigger an update in Meteor) so you should add `getReactively` when you use them.

Here is an example of your need:

```
<tr  class="ng-scope" align="center" ng-repeat="wordsList in
    words">
```

---

```
this.bundles = 'some bundle thing';

this.helpers({
  words: () => {
    return words.find({bundles: this.getReactively('bundles')});
  }
});
```

of course, if querying bundles from words requires more complex query, you can use my example with any other Mongo query you like.

Comment: this is returning me nothing                                            this.bundles="_id";


            this.helpers({
                    words: () => {
               // this.bundles=bundles.text.bundleId;
                return words.find({bundles: this.getReactively('bundles')});
    //console.log("variable",abc);

        }
        });

Comment: but if he wants to load the words() based on another object? list of words by a user? considering all users, not just the one logged in?

Comment: how he will change the bundle on the html?